# LIthium 18650 discharge voltage

Tags: constant-current, lithium, over-discharge

I am capacity testing 18650 batteries from old laptops using constant current, previously I used 2.8V as discharge/cutoff voltage but now raised the value to 3.0V

Discharge current is 1Amp.

I know discharge voltages depends on battery specifications but my use case is broad and I can't check datasheets of each and every battery, jumping from 2.8V to 3.0V makes a huge difference in total measured capacity but I think I might be destroying batteries discharging them too low.

What should be generally safe discharge voltage as people have their own opinion on internet, some go as low as 2.5 while others suggest anything below 3.0 is a disaster.

Comment: How do you calculate the capacity if it makes a _huge_ difference?

Comment: total discharge time in millisec /3600 = Capacity in mAh @pipe and using lower 2.8V limit increases discharge time and hence measured capacity, your question is confusing as I stated I am not measuring them according to specs but comparatively to each other.

Comment: Could you also be experiencing degradation, since these are old batteries?

Comment: yes sometimes 2200mAh batteries only yield 400~500mAh but if bms failed detecting single pair of faulty batteries (2 out of 6 in laptop) other pairs (4 cells) can still be 1500~1800mAh, faulty ones are usually unusable and get disposed @rdtsc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have figured out yourself, it depends on specifik make and model of the battery.

If you want to find a *universally* safe cutoff voltage, I'd say 3.0 V is probably what you'll want to use. I don't think I've ever seen a lithium-ion battery specifying a higher cut off voltage than that. But as there are many batteries that specify 3.0 V as minimum cut off, you don't want to go lower than that.

If you check the datasheet of every battery you will test, you could possibly go lower on some of them, but discharging below 3.0 V will most likely not be *universally* safe.

The voltage of pretty much all lithium-ion cells will start dropping pretty quickly below 3.0 V with a moderate discharge current, so it really shouldn't make *that* much of a difference.